# Создание диалоговых окон

Tags: c++

Можно ли создать диалоговое окно и полноценно работать с ним в Dev C++, если имеется уже  подключенная библиотека graphics.h ?

Comment: В таком случае лучше пользоваться визуальной средой. Наиболее популярная - Visual C++

Answer (score 1):

А какое отношение к созданию окон имеет хедер graphics.h? Далее, причем тут DevC++ - тут важен компилятор. --- Ну есть в DevC++ какая-та заготовка виджета диалогового окна (wx). Зачем она нужна? Под Win используйте WinAPI, MFC (в качестве IDE - MS VS), что-бы не париться - используйте IDE Borland C++ (Embarcadero сейчас)- там с помощью классов VCL вообще все просто. Но вдруг Вы захотите кросс-код - тогда "копайте" Qt.

Answer (score -1):

нет невозможно

Comment: Тьфу ты...что за чушь! А как же WinApi:

       MessageBox()
       CreateWindow()
       CreateWindowEx()

???

Comment: какой winapi в graphics.h? и ктому же перечисленные вами функции не предназначены для работы с диалоговыми окнами

Comment: @aramcpp, не говорите о том, чего не знаете, или очень плохо понимаете...посмотрите на MSDN значение данных функций =)

Comment: а вы что диалог через CreateWindow создаете? Может так и правилнее но мне привычнее старый добрый DialogBox

Comment: Здесь суть вопроса в:

       Можно ли создать диалоговое окно и полноценно работать с ним в Dev C++

Comment: а вот это есть в конце, из-за этой сточки я и сказал что невозможно
> если имеется уже подключенная библиотека graphics.h ?